# Solutions to $\sqrt{3 - \tan^2(\frac{3x}{2})} \cdot \sin x - \cos x = 2$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$$\sqrt{3 - \tan^2(\frac{3x}{2})} \cdot \sin x - \cos x = 2.$$

How can such an equation be solved? I don't know where to start?

My attempt: $$(3 - \frac{\sin^2 3 y}{\cos^2 3 y}) \cdot 2 \cos y \sin y = (3 - 2 \sin^2 y)^2$$, where $y = \frac{x}{2}$. This does not simplify anything at all, I do not understand what to do next

Comment: You could start by adding $\cos x$ to both sides and then square both sides.

Comment: Let $x/2 = \theta$. We have $$ \sqrt{3 - \tan^2(3\theta)}\cdot \sin(2\theta) - \cos(2\theta) = 2.$$ You have formulae for $\tan(3\theta), \sin(2\theta), \cos(2\theta)$.

Comment: I tried, it just makes it harder

Comment: @Viktor I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: My attempt: $$(3 - \frac{\sin^2 3 y}{{\cos^2 3 y} \cdot 2 \cos y \sin y = (3 - 2 \sin^2 y)^2$$, where $$y = x / 2$$. This does not simplify anything at all, I do not understand what to do next

Answer (score 1):

By transferring $\cos x$ to the RHS and squaring, we have
$$(3 - \tan^2\tfrac32x)\sin ^2x=(2+\cos x)^2.$$
Using the fact that $\cos^2x+\sin^2x=1$, some rearrangement gives
$$(\tan\tfrac32x\sin x)^2+(1+2\cos x)^2=0.$$
A real solution to this equation would simultaneously require, modulo $2\pi$, that $x=0$ and $x=\pm\frac23\pi$. Since these requirements are inconsistent, the original equation has no solution.